# bootstrap 4 modal not showing

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

[This is my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yryA.png) I am working on Bootstrap 4 modal, actually i want to get form values in the bootstrap 4 modal but its not showing, can someone check my code i don't know why its not responding ?
when i click on edit button it do nothing. I am using Mysql, Php, Bootstrap and Javascript.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click','.edit_data', function(){
          var project_id=$(this).attr("id");
   $.ajax({
            URL:"adminhome.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{projectID:project_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
               $('#pt').val(data.pt);
               $('#s1_id').val(data.s1_id);
               $('#s1_name').val(data.s1_name);
               $('#s2_id').val(data.s2_id);
               $('#s2_name').val(data.s2_name);
               $('#s3_id').val(data.s3_id);
               $('#s3_name').val(data.s3_name);
               $('#project_id').val(data.id);
               $('#update_user_modal').modal('show'); 
        }

                                          });

                               });

                      });
```

```html
 <a  class="btn btn-warning btn-sm mt-1  text-white edit_data"  role="button" name="edit" id="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" >
                <span class="">EDIT</span>
              </a>

    <!-- Modal - Update User details -->
<div class="modal fade" id="update_user_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form method="post" id="insert_form"> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_title">Project Title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="pt" name="pt" placeholder="Project Title" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_student_id1">Student ID 1</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_student_id1" id="s1_id" name="s1_id" placeholder="Student ID" class="form-control"/>
                    <label for="update_student_name1">Student Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_student_name1" id="s1_name" name="s1_name" placeholder="Student Name" class="form-control"/>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_student_id2">Student ID 2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_student_id2"  id="s2_id" name="s2_id" placeholder="Student ID" class="form-control"/>
                    <label for="update_student_name2">Student Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_student_name2" id="s2_name" name="s2_name" placeholder="Student Name" class="form-control"/>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="update_student_id3">Student ID 3</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_student_id3" id="s3_id" name="s3_id" placeholder="Student ID" class="form-control"/>
                    <label for="update_student_name3">Student Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="update_student_name3" id="s3_name" name="s3_name" placeholder="Student Name" class="form-control"/>

                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdateUserDetails()" >Save Changes</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="project_id">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first thing i notice is that your update_user_modal doesn't have aria-hidden="true"
So technically when you load the page it is already displayed and your code $('#update_user_modal').modal('show');  isn't going to do much. So if you don't see a modal at the start now could you check if you implemented the bootstrap modal library correctly? also if i remember correctly you need a data-toggle="modal" to trigger it?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
                                                                                                                           <script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>                                                      
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">

Comment: Ok, I ran your code in my own editor, and your code works perfectly if you exclude the ajax call and just put $('#update_user_modal').modal('show');  in the onclick event. So this means your problem is going to be within your ajax call it probably fails on something. try this for yourself to see if your modal pop-ups. If this works for you do an alert of your variable project_id to see if it return the correct id you want. here's your code without the ajax in codepen: https://codepen.io/mrdeadsven/pen/MXyrPM?editors=1010

Comment: You are right the problem is with the ajax call. And it is getting the right project-id

Comment: ok, then you can start debugging from here on. I can't really help a lot here since I don't know how you made everything on the server etc. But most common mistakes are that the URL is wrong, the data is incorrect and that kind of stuff. Also try type:"POST" instead of method idk why but some people have issues regarding when they use method instead of type.